# SharePoint 2013 List Box view customize web part display

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am referencing a list in a web part on a SharePoint page. In that web part I am using the "Boxed" view.  However, I would like to customize the way that box looks a bit. Some examples would be to provide more space between the columns, bold the left column, shade every other row, etc. Included is an example of what it looks like now and why I want to change it a bit.

[Click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrYpG.jpg)

I have looked for answers for this and I have found some possibilities using jQuery (http://www.surfpointtech.com/2014/05/20/cleaner-list-view-boxed-style-using-jquery/), but I have not been successful in applying it to the page because when I try adding it to the script editor it doesn't work. I am obviously not applying it to the page correctly. Can someone provide some guidance on how to apply this to the page correctly? I have not used jQuery with SharePoint pages all that much.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what platform you are using, if you are using SharePoint 2013, it would be recommended to using a JS Link, via the following [page](http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2013-using-the-spfield-jslink-property-to-change-the-way-your-field-is-rendered-in-sharepoint-2013), which you can modify from the List View Web Part (under Miscellaneous). With the JSLink, you can then manipulate corresponding fields, styling, etc. Likewise, you can use SharePoint Designer, adding a stylesheet, to overwrite the properties of the given control.

Also, just to add, you will likely get additional feedback, if you leverage the [http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/), as the questions and answers are dedicated to SharePoint.